# Intent Architect: How can I define an attribute of type IDictionary<TKey, TValue> (specifying the generic types) on a class?

Tags: c#, intent-architect

When adding attributes to a Class, how do I add an attribute of type IDictionary<String, String> (for example). I can specify whether an attribute is a collection, but not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to handle this is to create the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` as a Type-Definition in the Designer. You can then set this as the reference type for your attribute.

To create this Type-Definition:

1. Right-click on the Package / Folder and select the `New Type` option.
2. Set the name to `IDictionary`.
3. In the properties for this Type, add two Generic types by clicking `Add Type` in the `Generic Types` field. Call these `TKey` and `TValue`, for example.

This type will immediately be available as an option for your attribute's type-reference. You be able to set the types for each of the generic arguments as sub-elements of the attribute.